# How do I properly use '/=' haskell infix operator for xor?

Tags: haskell, xor, infix-notation

I'm learning haskell and I'm having an issue getting a line of code to work. The error says it is specifically to do with my "/=" operator. Could anyone help me properly use it?

Thank you.

```
e = filter (\(x, y, _) -> (x `elem` ed) `(/=)` (y `elem` ve)) es
```

Comment: Backticks are for turning identifiers of functions into infix operators. `/=` is already an infix operator; you don't need to turn it into a prefix function with `(...)` in a (futile) effort to turn it back into an infix operator.

Comment: Joke: ``(`(`(`(/=)`)`)`)``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply write `/=` as a normal [infix  operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator):

```
e = filter (\(x, y, _) -> (x `elem` ed) /= (y `elem` ve)) es
```

Comment: Well how about that? So simple. I need to learn how to read documentation better. Thank you. I'll accept this answer once I'm able. There's a timer.